# How to change font family of Android Date Picker?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to change the font family of the android date picker

```
<DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/dob_picker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Answer (score 1):

create a theme, ex

```
    <style name="PickerTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>
    </style>
```

then

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/dob_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:theme="@style/PickerTheme"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />
```

Comment: that's weird, because it's work on my end, did you use a right font?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing issue in 2022,
create theme first:

```
  <style name="PickerTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>
    </style>
```

and add this line to layout:

```
        app:theme="@style/PickerTheme"
```

Instead of `android:theme`  so try this this worked for me.